# How to replace the user input file path using bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to replace the filepath in the file based on the user input. I am not seeing any replacement happening in my file.

**My file**

```
   paths:              
      - /var/log/*.log
```

**My bash script**

```
echo 'Enter the log directory path'
read log_path
sed -i -e 's/    - \/var\/log\/*.log/    - $log_path/g' /envs/cfc/fmn.txt
```

I am not sure where I am doing wrong.

Comment: This is YAML? I'd use a language with actual YAML parsing and generation facilities, rather than trying to shoehorn bash into a job it's not well-suited for.

Comment: That said, if you want more reliable search-and-replace functionality than what's offered by `sed` (not needing content to be escaped in any way), see `gsub_literal` in [BashFAQ #21](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021).

Comment: Also see the shell function `replace` (in the same FAQ entry) defined to call Perl with origin and replacement strings passed as environment variables -- that'll do the job as well (though with the same caveats as any non-syntax-aware tooling in that there's no guarantee that its output will actually be well-formed YAML). Since `perl -i` exists, it's a direct drop-in replacement for `sed -i`.

Comment: gsub_literal. It says command not found.

Comment: `gsub_literal` is a function which is defined in the text of the page I linked to -- you need to actually run the definition from that page to make it available.

Answer (score -1):

Well, first of all, you are trying to get variable expansion inside single quotes, which is impossible. It should be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Enter the log directory path: ' log_path
sed -i -e "s#/var/log/\*.log#$log_path#g" ./file.txt
```

Comment: Another thing is asterisk

Comment: It'd make things much easier to use a sigil other than `/` as your separator. Right now, this code will fail because the `/`s in the `log_path` won't be escaped.